# Does Java 8 provide Locking Priority?

Tags: java, java-8, locking, readerwriterlock

I have one writer object and multiple reader objects.
They read/write to single object "StateObject"

Reader:

```
ReadLock
Read StateObject
ReadUnlock
```

Writer:

```
WriteLock
Update StateObject
WriteLock
```

Assume that currently 5 outof 10 readers holding ReadLock:

```
At time t1, Writer issues writeLock request
At time t2 > t1, 3 Readers issue ReadLock request
```

Now my requirement is since writer has already asked for writeLock, other 3 read threads should not get ReadLock and after first 5 threads done with ReadLock, Writer should get Lock

Is there any Java8 Locking mechanism that suppports this ?

Comment: I think you are looking for a ReadWriteLock(true) - The ReadWriteLock prioritizes the write lock acquisition and allows multiple threads to obtain the read lock simultaneously.

Comment: @JohnnyV, ReadWriteLock doesn't always proiritize writers over readers. If the number of waiting readers is large enough and they've been waiting for long time, they might overweight a waiting writer.

Comment: @AndrewLygin I'll have to look at the docs but I believe they say that the writer has a higher priority than readers. How that priority plays out in the scenario you suggested I don't know.

Comment: @JohnnyV, technically you are right in saying that a writer has higher priority than a reader. But many long-waiting readers are treated as a single group that might take priority over a writer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

Comment: I have answered a similar question. Check this out, might be that will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466493/java-locks-and-thread-priority/75971786#75971786