# Java locks and thread priority?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have some code, where a lot of threads might be waiting on a lock while a certain Thread updates some resources at a fixed interval provided by a timer. The timed thread should ideally be the one to be woken up when the lock is unlocked in case it is waiting on the lock. Is there a lock in Java that respects thread priorities? I looked at e.g. Guava's Monitor implementation and it doesn't look at priorities at all.

I know this is a research topic for real-time systems and there are many standard algorithms for this, but I don't have strict latency guarantees. I mainly just need a well-tested implementation.

Comment: In this case I'd recommend you try a read / write lock.
Take a look here
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html

Comment: Not sure how an RW lock will help? I have a critical section that can only be entered by one thread at a time (i.e. we don't have multiple readers that can simultaneously enter, which is the case for an RW lock). When multiple threads are waiting on the lock, I just want a specific thread to have priority over all others when entering. This is not the semantics of an RW lock.

Comment: @eof The RW lock was probably suggested because your question is hard to understand. Could you please show us some pseudocode or anything that would illustrate what you want better? Why is the special lock that signals the normal locks waiting on the same lock at all?

Comment: @eof Do you have a limit on no of thread who waits for lock? is it fixed no of thread?

Comment: Also do you have a way by which you can uniquely identify the thread? you would need  that to identify the thread that needs to be woken up.

Comment: Could you perhaps design it differently? E.g. A single thread is in charge of doing the critical section, and it's waiting on a queue of requests from the other threads. You can then make this a priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is an out-of-the-box solution. Both Java locks API and `synchronized` blocks do not guarantee that *some particular Thread* will be given a lock.

Still, I can think of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, for instance, you can have something like:

```
public synchronized Object read() {
    if (!readWriteLock.isWriteLocked()) {
        ReadLock lock = null;
        try {
            lock = readWriteLock.readLock();
            // do smth
            return data;
        } catch (Thrwoable t) {
             return null;
        } finally {
            if (lock != null) lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public void write() {
   Lock lock = null;
   try {
       lock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
       // do stuff
   } catch (Thrwoable t) {
   } finally {
       if (lock != null) lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

Here, our reads synchronized and each time before acquiring the lock they check if the lock is already acquired. To make it even better, you can use a `ReadWriteLock` in fair mode. It is more costly in terms of performance, but this way you will ensure, that even if read comes before write, the next read will not acquire the lock, since the write is waiting longer.

Of course it ***still does not guarantee that the write will always go first if present***, but at least there is a check for a WriteLock existence and we increase the chances, whereas just `synchronized` will choose the thread without any guarantees.